# Example of why downcast is not allowed and if it's done then why it's unsafe

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
  public:
      virtual void display(){
        std::cout<<"A Class"<<std::endl;
      }
};

class B: public A{
  public:
        void show(){
          std::cout<<"B Class"<<std::endl;
        }
};

int main() 
{
    A *ob = new B();
    ob->display();//A Class
    B *ob1 = (B*)(ob);
    ob1->show();//B Class

    A *obj = new A();
    B *obj1 = (B*)obj;
    obj1->display();//A Class
    obj1->show();//B Class
    
    return 0;
}
```

Above is the example for upcasting and downcasting.
My questions are -

1. Why downcasting is not allowed and if its done why explicitly need to be done.
2. Why downcasting is unsafe and its considered as a bad design.

I have read over internet every answer but, didn't get any proper answer with example.

So, can anyone explain about the same with some easy example ?

Comment: A downcast can be performed on an object that is of the downcast type.  If the object is not of that type, it is **undefined behavior**.  A downcast — or any cast — is telling the compiler "ignore the errors, just do it; trust me, I know what I'm doing".  If you lie to the compiler, the compiler will believe you.

Comment: I know that stuff that is what I was getting from other sites. 
I want to know why downcast is not allowed plus why the explicit casting is required for the same and plus why the object should of derived class type.
I want to know from the coding perspective through a code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed your example a bit so that error get more obvious:

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
  public:
      virtual void display(){
        std::cout<<"A Class"<<std::endl;
      }
};

class B: public A{
  int* s=new int;
  public:
        void show(){
          std::cout<<"B Class"<<*s<<std::endl;
        }
};

int main() 
{
    A *ob = new B();
    ob->display();//A Class
    B *ob1 = (B*)(ob);
    ob1->show();//B Class

    A *obj = new A();
    B *obj1 = (B*)obj;
    obj1->display();//A Class
    obj1->show();//B Class
    
    return 0;
}
```

The change I did is adding a member variable to B and print its value. So when you create an object of type A and downcast it to B, where do you think that that member has been initialized?
And the answer ist that it was never initialised and that not even some memory was reserved for it.

Comment: Okay tell me if I am wrong so, as per your example as per I believe if we have a constructor in class B that will be initializing memory for class B data member then if we straight away downcast the pointer of base class to derived class then here the constructor of class B will not be called as a new pointer of class B type will just be pointing to already created memory location (object of A) no new object of class B will not be created.
So, here s will not get any initialization resulting in run time error that will be segmentation fault.

Comment: @Fedrick • "... will be segmentation fault"  It will be **undefined behavior**.  That may manifest as a segmentation fault.  Or it may manifest as appearing to work.  Or it may email your browser history to your grandmother, and then format your hard drive.

Comment: And consider my example also that is what you were saying

#include <iostream>
class A{
int *x;
public:
A(){ std::cout<<"A Called"<<std::endl; x = new int; }
 virtual void display(){  std::cout<<"A Class"<<" "<<*x<<std::endl; }
};
class B: public A{
int* s;
public:
B(){ s = new int;  std::cout<<"B Called"<<std::endl; }
void show(){ std::cout<<"B Class"<<*s<<std::endl; }
};
int main(){ A *ob = new B(); ob->display();//A Class
B *ob1 = (B*)(ob); ob1->show();//B Class
A *obj = new A(); B *obj1 = (B*)obj;
    obj1->display();//A Class
    obj1->show();//B Class
return 0;
}

Comment: @Eljay Okay that was totally a different kind of undefined behavior I have ever heard.
No Worries it may happen.
Anything can happen.

Comment: @Fedrick • A coworker of mine wrote up a blog post about how **undefined behavior** can even cause [time travel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).

Comment: @Eljay That was a great post will definitely look into the same and lastly one more question
Was it right to say that the object of B is not created when we were downcasting in above code just another pointer of B type is created with a new memory block containing data members of class B
and one last question "Why do we have to explicitly typecast in case of downcasting and not in upper cast ?" Is is a pre defined design in c++

Comment: @Fedrick • An up-cast of a pointer-or-reference to a derived class to a pointer-or-reference of its base class is always safe.  A down-cast is dangerous unless the object actually is the cast-to type, and the compiler (probably) cannot check that at compile time.